# Блоки с разными классами с новой строки

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно чтобы один класс был в одной строке, второй класс во второй и т д. Причем классы могут быть разные, и их может быть много.
Возможно, это можно сделать с помощью js, но пока ничего не приходит на ум.

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
  <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
  <li class="third">Третий класс<li>
</ul>
```

Comment: то есть `first` на одной строке `second` в другой и т.д.?Я правильно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: Да, но классы могут быть разные и их может быть много, то есть прописывать каждое имя класса в css или js не годится

Comment: да очень интересная задача

Comment: Я думал, может сделать какую то проверку, и если верхний класс не равен нижнему от него, то добавлять <br> или что-то типа того

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может сделать это через CSS `float` + `clear`?

```css
.first + .second,
.second + .third {
  clear: left;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="first">Один класс</li>
 <li class="first">Один класс</li>
 <li class="first">Один класс</li>
 <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
 <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
 <li class="third">Третий класс</li>
</ul>
```

---

А вот и вариант в котором css составлен автоматически:

```js
document.write(`<style>${[...document.querySelectorAll('ul li')].reduce((acc, el) => {
  return acc[acc.length-1] !== el.className && acc.push(el.className), acc
}, []).map((e,i,a) => `.${e} + .${a[i+1]}`).join(',')} {clear: left;}</style>`);
```

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="first">Один класс</li>
 <li class="first">Один класс</li>
 <li class="first">Один класс</li>
 <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
 <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
 <li class="third">Третий класс</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, но автор указал, что прописывание вручную - не вариант. Попробуйте мой вариант переделать, уверен, у вас это выйдет лучше :)

Comment: @VitaliyAntal скрипт добавьте не в header а в конец страницы

Comment: Заработало и на сайте. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @VitaliyAntal нет проблем, предлагаю по удалять комменты

Answer (score 4):

Решение, уверен, что костыльное, но может за счёт него напишут вариант лучше.

```js
let arrClass = $('ul > li').map(function(){return $(this).attr('class')}).get(); // собираем в массив все существующие классы li

arrClass = unique(arrClass); // перебираем классы, оставляя только "уникальные"

arrClass.forEach((e)=>{ // проходим циклом по всем "уникальным" классам
  $('.'+e).wrapAll('<ul class="wrap_'+e+'">'); // оборачиваем эти классы
});

// функция для поиска "уникальных" классов
function unique(arr){
  let obj = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let str = arr[i];
    obj[str] = true;
  }
  return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul > ul::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
ul > ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
ul > ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.wrap_first {color: blue;}
.wrap_second {color: red;}
.wrap_third {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="third">Третий класс</li>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
  <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
  <li class="third">Третий класс</li>
  <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
  <li class="third">Третий класс</li>
  <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Просто убери свойство `float` в стилях:

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  /*float:left;*/
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="first">Один класс</li>
  <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
  <li class="second">Второй класс</li>
  <li class="third">Третий класс
    <li>
</ul>
```